# How to animate object left to match same pixel width as the window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

When I click the `.trigger` i want the object positioned at `{left: '0'}` to move left to match the same pixels to whatever the pixel width of the browser window is. Can someone help me figure this out. This is what I've worked together so far, I can't figure out the function that needs to go after `else.. {left: 'pixel width of browser window'}`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Prompt
    $('.trigger').live('click', toggleName);

    function toggleName() {
        if ($("#some-id").attr('data-state') == 'open') $("#some-id").animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
            $(this).attr('data-state', 'close')
        }), ;
        else $("#some-id").animate({
            left: 'pixel width of browser window'
        }, 500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
            $(this).attr('data-state', 'open')
        }), ;
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Why not use $(window).width() ? I probably miss something in your question...

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, please explain in more detail.

Comment: No, that's helpful, would it look like: {left: '$(window).width()'} ?

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on` to delegate the events to an ancestor element. Additionally, you have a syntax error in your code on the 10th line.

Comment: @BeDesinged, drop the single quotes/quotes. IMHO, assigning a `left` value is always better to use a numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function to get the width of the window :

```
 else $("#some-id").animate({
        left: $(window).width()
 }, ...
```

This will move the div to the right and let it leave the window (depending on your css).

If you want the div to go stick to the right, you'd better use `right: 0` instead.

Comment: Awesome! it worked. Sorry for making it more confusing than it needed to be.

Comment: @Asad I'm not sure either. I supposed the goal was to *animate* the div away to the right.